# How can I find a numerical approximation of a multivariable non-linear equation?

Tags: matlab, graph, octave, equation

I've been working on a project for my engineering school. We have to create a mathematical framework allowing us to understand the transformation from two input angles to one output point. The robot we are working on is a 5 bar parallel kinematic robot.

[image]

We have found the equation and we managed to find the trajectory.

We have now the error equation which is really good because, for a given point in space, we can find the angles required to achieve minimum error.

[image]

This is the error equation. Now we are struggling to find a way to compute all the angles so that the equation equals zero.

I wanted to visualize the graph from 0 to 2*pi for both variables. But on Octave and Matlab, I always end up with an ill matrix making it impossible to use. And now we just don't know what we can do?

[image]

Does anyone have any advice for me?

PS : this is the code I was using :

```
clear

X = 0.5;
Y = 0.5;
L = 1.0;
E = 1.0;

discret = 0.06;

x = [0:discret:2*pi];
y = [0:discret:2*pi];

[xx, yy] = meshgrid (x, y);

Cx = cos(xx)
Sx = sin(xx)
Cy = cos(yy)
Sy = sin(yy)
D = (((-2*(L*Cx - E)+(2*(E - L*Cy))))/((-2*(L)*Sy)+(2*(L)*Sx)));
K = ((-E+L*Cx)^2 - (E-L*Cy)^2 - (L*Sy)^2 - (L*Sx)^2)/((-2*(L)*Sy)+(2*(L)*Sx));
z = abs(Y - X*D - K);

mesh(x, y, z)
meshc(xx,yy,z) 
xlabel ("theta1");
ylabel ("theta2");
zlabel ("Er(theta1,theta2)");
grid on
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, it'll be better if you put your octave code block with your question

Comment: yes sure ! I tried representing the graph to see if the relation was the right one.

Answer (score 2):

The bit about precision is hinting that you are performing matrix division, when in fact judging from your equations, you only seem to need normal array division (i.e. an elementwise/vectorised operation, not a matrix operation).

Simply replace any `/` or `^` with `./`, `.^` etc as appropriate.
Also, your equations can be simplified significantly to make your code slightly clearer and avoid bugs due to legibility:

```octave
clear
X = 0.5;  Y = 0.5;  L = 1.0;  E = 1.0;  stepsize = 0.06;
x = [0 : stepsize : 2*pi];  y = [0 : stepsize : 2*pi];
[xx, yy] = meshgrid (x, y);
Cx = cos(xx);  Sx = sin(xx);  Cy = cos(yy);  Sy = sin(yy);
D  = ( Cy + Cx - 2 .* E/L ) ./ ( Sy - Sx );
K  = 0.5 .* ( Sy.^2 + Sx.^2 + (Cy - E/L).^2 - (Cx - E/L).^2 ) ./ (Sy-Sx);
z  = abs(Y - X .* D - K);

surf(x, y, z, 'edgecolor', 'none', 'facecolor', 'interp' )
set( gcf, 'colormap', hot(256), 'color', 'k' )
set( gca, 'gridcolormode', 'manual', 'gridlinestyle', '-', 'gridcolor', 'w', 'gridalpha', 0.1, 'fontsize', 16, 'color', [0.2, 0.2, 0.2], 'xcolor', [0.8,0.8,0.8], 'ycolor', [0.8,0.8,0.8], 'zcolor', [0.8,0.8,0.8] )
set( get( gca, 'xlabel' ), 'string', '\theta_1', 'fontsize', 36 );
set( get( gca, 'ylabel' ), 'string', '\theta_2', 'fontsize', 36 );
set( get( gca, 'zlabel' ), 'string', {'Er( \theta_1, \theta_2 )',''}, 'fontsize', 36 );
view( 15, 30 );
```

[image]